# Windows 7 Change Context Menu Hotkey

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I'm looking for a way to change the hotkey letters in the Windows 7 right-click context menu. I've added a new entry into my registry, "Edit with Vim" and the default hotkey is E. This conflicts with the "Edit" option which also has a hotkey of E, so I'd like to modify the registry in order to set the "Edit with Vim" option with a hotkey of V instead.

Can anyone help guide me in modifying the registry? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Assume you add "Edit with Vim" command to the context menu of `.txt` file. This extension is usually associated with `txtfile` key. The commands are listed in the `shell` subkey. The default value of the command key is the name of the command displayed in the context menu. If you add `&` before any of the characters, then the following character becomes the keyboard accelerator.

Let me explain using an example.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
    .txt
        (Default) = txtfile

    txtfile
        shell
            EditInVim
                (Default) = Edit with Vim
```

In this case, the command *Edit with Vim* would not have an accelerator key. Change the value to `Edit with &Vim`, and then `V` would be underlined and pressing it will invoke the command.

If your editor uses a context menu handler to add the item to the context menu, then the only way to change the accelerator key is to edit the string resources in its executable file.

---

I didn't answer the original question though.

The default *Edit* command for text files comes from the following registry keys:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
    SystemFileAssociations
        text
            shell
                edit
                    (Default) = (value not set)
```

The shell make the first letter the accelerator. To change it, assign the value to `(Default)`:

```
                    (Default) = E&dit
```

The accelerator for *Edit* command has changed to `d` now.